# installed imagick and ghostscript on centos but convert command and gs command not working with sudo

Tags: php, linux, ghostscript, imagick

I have installed Imagick and Ghostscript on Centos but convert and gs commands are not working with sudo i.e. I cannot run both the commands as root user. It shows command not found for the Root User but it runs properly for Normal User.
I also tried installing both Imagick and Ghostscript in root user's home directory but the issue is still the same.
Could anyone tell me how to install Imagick 7 and Ghostscript 9.20 on centos?

Comment: I'd have to guess that the install directory simply isn't in PATH for the root user, have you checked ?

Comment: I fixed it by using pathenv('path_to_imagick') function of php. I set the path manually using this function and then it worked.

Comment: its putenv not pathenv